# SQL Server query takes nearly 3 hours

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Below is my query that takes more than 2 hours to retrieve the result, and I am not sure why. These tables have 200 000 records.

```
    INSERT INTO tempoutput12345 (tempitm, templitm, URRF_Configurator_Item) 
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        [KYKIT] 'IBITM', iblitm, 'CFG_ITEM' 
    FROM  
        [database].[production].[PRODDTA].[tableF3293] with (nolock)
    JOIN  
        [database].[production].[PRODDTA].[tablef4102] with (nolock) ON  
    kykit = ibitm 
    WHERE
        EXISTS (SELECT templitm FROM tempoutput12345 
                WHERE templitm = iblitm)
        AND IBMCU LIKE '%'+'5217194'
        AND 1 = 1

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT DISTINCT
        [KYITM] 'IBITM', iblitm, 'CFG_ITEM' 
    FROM     
        [database].[production].[PRODDTA].[tableF3293] with (nolock) 
    JOIN     
        [database].[production].[PRODDTA].[tablef4102] with (nolock) ON 
    kyitm = 

    ibitm 
    WHERE 
        EXISTS (SELECT templitm FROM tempoutput&jobid& 
                WHERE templitm = iblitm)
        AND IBMCU LIKE '%'+'5217194'
        AND 1 = 1

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT DISTINCT 
        [RDITM] 'IBITM', iblitm, 'CFG_ITEM' 
    FROM    
        [database].[production].[PRODDTA].[tableF3283] with (nolock)
    JOIN     
        [database].[production].[PRODDTA].[tablef4102] with (nolock) ON 
    rditm = ibitm 
    WHERE    
        EXISTS (SELECT templitm FROM tempoutput&jobid& 
                WHERE templitm = iblitm) 
        AND IBMCU LIKE '%'+'5217194'
        AND 1 = 1;
```

The above query will take longer time. please help me it out for this

Comment: What does your query plan tell you?

Comment: Probably want to start with those where exists sub-queries.... you are going deeper than the movie inception. Regardless... check the query plan.

Comment: Run the actual (or even estimated) execution plan, paste it into www.pastetheplan.com and give us the link. Without this it's going to be difficult to see where your problem lies.

Comment: Missing some indexes I'd wager.

Comment: Indexing isn't likely going to help here. There are several nonSARGable predicates. Anytime there is a leading wildcard with a LIKE you will get a scan.

Comment: Also, those NOLOCK hints should not be used a performance tool. They carry a lot of baggage with them. Things like missing and/or duplicate rows and a whole host of other things most people don't realize. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Are you just server qualifying the tables `F3283` and `f4102`, or are they actually cross server queries? It is not clear which table `IBMCU` comes from, but if it is cross server you will likely find that the entirety of the two tables are being pulled from the remote DB into tempDB, then the filter applied. You might find better performance using `OPENQUERY` to bring over as few redundant records as possible.

Comment: Looks like you need to create a computed column for IBMCU, so that you have a column where you have the end part (which I assume is a fixed value you're looking for), so that you can create a query NEWCOLUMN = '5217194' -- and you need to index that column too.

Comment: Hi James, Yes iam lloking for fixed value for the column IBMCU. What you meant by create new query. Can you explain with some example.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hello GarethD.thanks.. IBMCU will come F4102 it is Oracle EDQ table. Please can you help it out..

Comment: can you explain what this is trying to do?

Comment: Run them individually and and see which is slowest and post the query plan.  Label the columns so we know with table they came from.

Comment: Hi, the second select query takes more time to exceute and  remaining first and third query excecuted in 5min. the columns 'kykit', kyitm will come from F3293 table and column 'rditm' from F3283 table and column 'ibitm', 'ibmcu' will come f4102 table.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no question is present, just statements.

Comment: I meant a new **column** not new query. See for example [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1682/using-computed-columns-in-sql-server-with-persisted-values/) blog post.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using distinct this is equivalent
Not sure if it will be faster

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [KYKIT] 'IBITM', iblitm, 'CFG_ITEM' 
FROM  
    [SRVGDYDHJSQL02].[JDE_PRODUCTION].[PRODDTA].[F3293] with (nolock)
JOIN  
    [SRVGDYDHJSQL02].[JDE_PRODUCTION].[PRODDTA].[f4102] with (nolock) 
       ON kykit = ibitm 
JOIN tempoutput12345 
       on templitm = iblitm
WHERE IBMCU LIKE '%5217194'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use SARG it will be fast. If there is no way to use SARG use only one table scan. Your qry is not optimized.

```
select distinct b.*
from (select * from f4102 where IBMCU  LIKE '%5217194') ib,
(
    select [RDITM] 'IBITM', iblitm, 'CFG_ITEM' from [f4102]
    union all
    select [KYKIT] 'IBITM', iblitm, 'CFG_ITEM' from [f4102]
    union all
    select [kyitm] 'IBITM', iblitm, 'CFG_ITEM' from [f4102]) b
where ib.ibitm = b.IBITM
```

Use index on IBMCU.ibitm, f4102.RDITM, f4102.kyitm, f4102.KYKIT if they are missing.

Don't use nolock everywhere - it's pityfull. If its necessary use it only for example as option with (nolock) on only one place.